# jax-ws, jaxb generic list wrapper

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, generic-list

I am trying to create generic list wrapper in my JAX-WS web service.

This is data model of my service:

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class Person {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int personId;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String personName;

    public int getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }

    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    }
}

@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GenericList <T> {

    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<T> item;

    public GenericList() {
        item = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public List<T> getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<T> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Application {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int applicationId;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private GenericList<Person> personList;

    public int getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(int applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    public GenericList<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }

    public void setPersonList(GenericList<Person> personList) {
        this.personList = personList;
    }
}
```

and this is code of my web service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "TestWs")
public class TestWs {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "response")
    public Application getApplication(@WebParam(name = "request") int applicationId) {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.setApplicationId(applicationId);

        GenericList<Person> personList = new GenericList<Person>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setPersonId(rand.nextInt(100));
        p1.setPersonName("Random 1");
        personList.getItem().add(p1);

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setPersonId(rand.nextInt(100));
        p2.setPersonName("Random 2");
        personList.getItem().add(p2);

        Person p3 = new Person();
        p3.setPersonId(rand.nextInt(100));
        p3.setPersonName("Random 3");
        personList.getItem().add(p3);

        app.setPersonList(personList);

        return app;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to call web service method `getApplication`, I am getting following error:

```
SEVERE: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class core.bean.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class core.bean.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:412)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:697)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class core.bean.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class core.bean.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.marshal(BridgeImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.marshal(Bridge.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.BridgeWrapper.marshal(BridgeWrapper.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:403)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class core.bean.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class core.bean.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:271)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class core.bean.Person nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:593)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:112)
    ... 47 more
```

Can you explain me what I am doing wrong, and how properly create generic list wrapper ?

Answer (score 0):

**@XmlRootElement**
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class Person {
.....

Comment: A short explanation would be great :)